# Xamarin Form manejo Uri tel no detecta mas de 9 digitos

Tags: xamarin, uri

¿Alguien sabe el comando `Device.OpenUri(new Uri("tel://" + numeroTelefono));` solo me redirecciona a mi aplicación de llamadas si tiene menos de 10 digitos, lo que pasa es que los numeros de celulares en Mexico son de 10 digitos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola despues de investigar al poner `"tel://" en Device.OpenUri(new Uri("tel://" + numeroTelefono));` solo me detecta menos de 10 digotos, pero solo basta con quitarle las // y entonces queda asi:

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("tel:" + numeroTelefono));
```

y con eso es más que suficiente.

Comment: me alegra mucho que hayas podido solucionar el problema. Te sugiero aceptar tu respuesta dentro de 24 horas, así ayudas a mantener la buena salud del sitio :D